# Check if an element contain specific text and add a new class to different elements

Tags: jquery, html

Based on a previous question of mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388969/if-div-contains-specific-word-add-a-new-class-in-parent-div-using-jquery), i have this code:

```js
var $categories = $('.menu-item-category');
$categories.each(function() {
  var $this = jQuery(this);
  if ($this.text().trim() == 'Offers') {
    $('.m3-item').addClass('menu-offers');
  }
});
```

```css
.menu-3-cat {
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding: 5px
}

.menu-item-category {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.m3-item {
  width: 48%;
  float: left;
}

.menu-offers {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-3-cat">
  <div class="menu-item-category">Offers</div>
  <div class="m3-item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="m3-item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="m3-item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="m3-item">Item 4</div>
</div>

<div class="menu-3-cat">
  <div class="menu-item-category">Smartphones</div>
  <div class="m3-item">Phone 1</div>
  <div class="m3-item">Phone 2</div>
  <div class="m3-item">Phone 3</div>
  <div class="m3-item">Phone 4</div>
</div>
```

I want on page load to check if the element with the class "menu-item-category" contains the word "Offers". If yes then i want to add a new class "menu-offers" to elements which have the class "m3-item" and are inside only in the BLOCK 1.

I tried the code below but it didn't work as it also add the new class even to the elements that belongs to BLOCK 2.

[Fiddle HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/d3s1gn3r/zr275jon/25/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it stands, with `$('.m3-item')` you collect *all* the `.m3-item` elements throughout the whole DOM, regardless of what's in `$this` element. Apparently, you need to limit the search with it.

You might use `$this` value as a starting point for parent node as context:

```
var $thisParent = $this.parent();
$('.m3-item', $thisParent).addClass('menu-offers');
```

Another approach is employing `$().nextAll()` method ([docs](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)) instead to get all the siblings of found item with given class:

```
var $categories = $('.menu-item-category');
$categories.each(function() {
  var $this = jQuery(this);
  if ($this.text().trim() == 'Offers') {
    $this.nextAll('.m3-item').addClass('menu-offers');
  }
});
```

---

But as a matter of fact, you don't even need all this code and stuff if you only want to check for `Offers` substring - behold the power of `:contains` ([docs](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)) pseudo-selector!

```js
$('.menu-item-category:contains(Offers) ~ .m3-item').addClass('menu-offers');
```

```css
.menu-3-cat {
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding: 5px
}

.menu-item-category {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.m3-item {
  width: 48%;
  float: left;
}

.menu-offers {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-3-cat">
  <div class="menu-item-category">Offers</div>
  <div class="m3-item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="m3-item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="m3-item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="m3-item">Item 4</div>
</div>

<div class="menu-3-cat">
  <div class="menu-item-category">Smartphones</div>
  <div class="m3-item">Phone 1</div>
  <div class="m3-item">Phone 2</div>
  <div class="m3-item">Phone 3</div>
  <div class="m3-item">Phone 4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to write the following jQuery code with your given HTML structure:

```
var menuItems = $(".menu-item-category");
menuItems.each(function(i){
    if($(this).text().indexOf("Offers") >= 0){
      $(this).siblings(".m3-item").addClass("menu-offers");
      alert(i + ":" + $(this));
  }
})
```

;

Here is a working example of the code:

```js
var menuItems = $(".menu-item-category");
menuItems.each(function(i){
 if($(this).text().indexOf("Offers") >= 0){
   $(this).siblings(".m3-item").addClass("menu-offers");
   alert(i + ":" + $(this));
  }
});
```

```css
.menu-offers{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- BLOCK 1 / START -->    
<div>
<div class="menu-3-cat">
<div class="menu-item-category">Offers</div>
<div class="m3-item">Item 1</div>
<div class="m3-item">Item 2</div>
<div class="m3-item">Item 3</div>
<div class="m3-item">Item 4</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- BLOCK 1 / END -->   


<!-- BLOCK 2 / START -->  
<div>
<div class="menu-3-cat">
<div class="menu-item-category">Smartphones</div>
<div class="m3-item">Phone 1</div>
<div class="m3-item">Phone 2</div>
<div class="m3-item">Phone 3</div>
<div class="m3-item">Phone 4</div>
</div>
</div>
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/thisisdg/k0x2usLr/7/) is the link to the fiddle.

Hope this was helpful.

---

**UPDATE:** I have updated the code according to your requirements, and please check that it works as you have mentioned in the question. I have added an additional CSS to the class that you wanted to add so that it becomes clear where the class is being added.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this Javascript method with Jquery:

```
var $categories = $('.menu-item-category');
$categories.each(function() {
  var $this = jQuery(this);
  if ($this.text().includes ('Offers') {
    $('.m3-item').addClass('menu-offers');
  }
});
```